# Angular 6 to Add Side Menu Bar is not Open

Tags: typescript, angular6

I'm still beginner for the Angular and I used my university project for `Angular 6`
I am trying to implement [This side nav](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav) but its not working in my project

[Live code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfy6yq)

That is my code
**facilitistatus.component.html**

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" (click)="open(closeNav)">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" (click)="open(openNav)">&#9776; open</span
```

**facilitistatus.component.ts**

```
openNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '250px';
}

closeNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0';
}
```

**facilitistatus.component.css**

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

I didn't see any error, anyone know how to do that correctly?

Thanks

Comment: In live code `app-component.html`, you call a method named `open` but the actual method name inside `app-component.ts` is `openNav`. I fixed it in the live code and it worked.

Comment: @Johna I understood sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling wrong function `open(openNav)`. There is no function containing `open(openNav)`. Change in your html template for open nav bar `(click)="openNav()"` instead of `(click)="open(openNav)"` and for close `(click)="open(closeNav)"` instead of `(click)="closeNav()"`.

here is working example: [Open close nav bar](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gs8q1)

Comment: Thanks sir, I understood

Comment: @core114 So now you can accept answer if it helps??

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" (click)="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" (click)="openNav()">&#9776;
```

open